# Does Ecmascript regular expression alternation operator (the pipe |) ensures evaluation order?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using Javascript (version 5, if it matters) and I have to store a string in a context where slashes are not allowed. When storing I mindlessly wrote:

```
mystring.replace(/(\\)|(\/)|(@)/g, function(_,rbar,bar,at) {
  if (rbar) return '@';
  if (bar) return '@b';
  if (at) return '@@';
} );
```

and its opposite when loading:

```
mystring.replace(/(@@)|(@b)|(@)/g, function(_,at,bar,rbar) {
  if (at) return '@';
  if (bar) return '/';
  if (rbar) return '\/';
} );
```

and apparently it works.

However, I have a doubt. Do ecmascript regular expressions ensure that the matching among the alternation operator are tested in order? So for example the second call will never return `'\/\/'` on an input of `'@@'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the order matters.

[Ecmascript](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-disjunction)

> The | regular expression operator separates two alternatives. The pattern first tries to match the left Alternative (followed by the sequel of the regular expression); if it fails, it tries to match the right Disjunction (followed by the sequel of the regular expression).

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) uses simpler wording:

> `x|y`   Matches 'x', or 'y' (if there is no match for 'x').